# New anonymous type filled by for-each cycle asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to simplify my code:

```
foreach (var data in dataList) //conversion of DB data to output data (Action is added)
            {
                result.Add(new
                {
                    data.Id,
                    data.Files,
                     .
                     .
                     .
                    Action =    HtmlTags.CreateEditButton() + 
                                HtmlTags.CreateDeleteButton()

                });
            }
```

in the "data" I have about 30 properties.

My question is - would it be possible to make something like this:

```
foreach (var data in dataList) //conversion of DB data to output data (Action is added)
            {
                result.Add(new
                {
                    foreach (var property in data.GetType().GetProperties()) //for each parameter
                    {
                        data.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(data),
                    }
                    Action =    HtmlTags.CreateEditButton() + 
                                HtmlTags.CreateDeleteButton()

                });
            }
```

I'm using this for sending data to view (DataTable) and I'm adding the buttons Edit and Delete to each item from database - I've choosen anonymous type, because I would need to doubled all the classes I have - just to add one item...

Comment: Why don't you use anonymous type with two properties `new { Data = data, Action = ... }`? In my opinion this approach has obvious implementation and easy to understand. The only drawback is that we need to write `Model.Data` on the `View` side.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to say something very uncontroversial. But maybe this is the time where you'd want to use dynamics

I got it to work using the following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var source = new SomeClass
    {
        Title = "Title",
        Description = "Test"
    };

    IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach(var pi in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
    {
        string propertyName = pi.Name;
        object propertyValue = pi.GetValue(source);

        result[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> property in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Key.ToString() + " " + property.Value.ToString());
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7ruAM

I hope this helps you solve your problem